# Check if two JSON Objects are equal, but with type placeholders for values

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

ok, we all know that there are enough java libraries to match json objects, for example gson and jackson.
these libraries can do everything I need (compare nested, disordered, "incomplete" objects). but now I'm trying to use placeholders for values of which I know the type but not the exact value. I am looking for a ready to use equalsWithTypePlaceholders(JSONObject object1, JSONObject object2) method. of course you can do this yourself, I personally would read the object, pick out the keys with placeholders, check if they match the right type, then delete these key value pairs from the json and use an equals() method from any library.

assuming I have prepared this pattern (object1)

```
[

  {
    "list": [
      {
        "id": "{int}",
        "anotherlist": [
          {
            "name": "{string}",
            "value": "abc"
          }
        ],
        "key": "{alphanumeric-string}",
        "name": "{alphanumeric-string}"
      }
    ],
    "key1":"value2"
  }
]
```

the following input (object2) should return true, because the existing values match and the placeholders were replaced with the correct type

```
[

  {
    "list": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "anotherlist": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "abc"
          }
        ],
        "key": "123asd",
        "name": "987asdas"
      }
    ],
    "key1":"value2"
  }
]
```

following input (object2) should return false, because an existing value does not match and 2 placeholders have the wrong type

```
[

  {
    "list": [
      {
        "id": "hello",
        "anotherlist": [
          {
            "name": "123",
            "value": "abcde"
          }
        ],
        "key": "123asd",
        "name": "312qwe"
      }
    ],
    "key1":"value2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736965/compare-two-json-which-has-same-nested-structure-and-same-keys-but-values-can-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing definitions here.
Your final task is not to check "equality", but to match against the schema.
So you should look into [json-schema](https://json-schema.org/) and [how to validate against it](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java)

```
"properties": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "id": {
        "type": "int",
    },
    "name": {
       "const": "exact value"
    }",
    .....
```

I think this will be the best direction for your further research.